# How can I import my Java packages into a js file

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to import my java packages into a js file and then call class methods on created object.

The reason I need to import is I wish to get data from a connection to my database, regarding dates  and I have a class that lets me do so.  So I need to import the Package, then create a class object, then call methods on my object.

I would appreciate your help, 
Thank you,
John

Comment: `java != javascript` REMEMBER IT!

Comment: `java` is to `javascript` what `ham` is to `hamsters` ;)

Comment: Also, Java (usually) runs on the server, JavaScript on the client. They can't interact directly with each other. You'll probably need to learn the basics of web development and/or client/server development before you can actually explain to us what you want to do.

Comment: **    java.equals(javascript)** will always return false

Answer (score 7):

The questions does not specify that this is a browser-based question.  Java ships with Rhino since version 6.  So, on the off chance that someone wants to know how to do this - e.g., using JavaScript as a scripting language for 3rd party tools like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html#4-javascript-support) or [PTC Integrity](http://communities.ptc.com/community/integrity) - it's incredibly simple.

```
importPackage(java.io);
```

Check out [Wikipedia:Rhino (JavaScript engine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) as a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSP and use Java basic types as parameter for your javascript.

Import your Java classes in JSP, e.g:

`<%@page import="com.acme.MyClass"%>`

Then in your JS which also in the JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var f = function(param){
 console.log(param);
}

f('<%= MyClass.foo().toString() %>');
</script>
```

Would that be something you're looking at?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you,I beleive this helps I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

I think solution for you problem is [DWR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWR_(Java)) technology. As I guessed you think that it is too easy to invoke Java methods(Server side) from JavaScript(Client side). DWR is exactly what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the Java as a Java server page on your server to do the connection, and feed javascript the database data via ajax, because javascript is incapable of connecting to any protocols other than http, file and ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN do this. You can create a Java Applet with public methods. Once you add this to your page you can access these methods via JavaScript.  I'll see if I can dig up a reference for you.

Here's [one link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html)!

I've done this myself, years ago. It works well. I don't know if I would do it again for the reason you specify, but it is possible.

Also in addition to this method and the many other fine suggestions, have a look at GWT. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html

Comment: That is probably not going to helpful. The original poster is mentioning database access, which usually is not sensibly possible in a Java Applet.

Comment: @rotora It's better than your suggestions. And I can imagine some scenarios where this IS the most useful suggestion here.

Answer (score -3):

Calling java methods from javascript is not possible.

JSP file:

```
function doSomething {
   <% SomeClass.someMethod(); %>
}

<%!
class SomeClass {
  public static void someMethod() {
    // 
  }
}
%>
```

someMethod will not run on invocation of doSomething but it will run when jsp generates response.

Comment: That blanket statement is not true. There are several ways for accessing Java methods from JavaScript. However the original question is not clear enough to be able determinate which way (if any at all) should be used.

Comment: I think it's not very straightforward to make a fool out of the questioner's knowledge gap.

Comment: I did not intended to make him fool. Added few more lines. Does this  makes sense now?

Comment: Making up syntax that doesn't work, doesn't prove that it's not possible.